# match innermost using regex in a scala string

Tags: regex, scala

I have sample data like below

```
header det1 det2 det3 header det1 det2 det3  innerdescription1 innerdescription2
```

I want to extract only innermost match using regex

i.e `val detail = "header det1 det2 det3 header det1 det2 det3  innerdescription1 innerdescription2"`

Here is my code :

```
val ptrn="""header .*? (innerdescription2)""".r
val head = ptrn.findAllIn(detail)
```

But its giving the entire data again. i.e from first header to innerdescription2. I am not able to find out how to get inner match here. . Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\bheader\b(?:(?!header).)*\binnerdescription2
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uo9zpg/1

Comment: Thanks vks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookups and I believe its supported in scala.

```
 (?<=header).*?(?=innerdescription2)
```

Comment: I had tried this as well. But Its just gave me entire string again. "header det1 det2 det3 header det1 det2 det3  innerdescription1 innerdescription2"